# API convention for parent -> child element calls

Tags: api, rest

We are trying to figure out if there is a generally accepted way of providing an API parent -> child resource. Say we have a Person entity and each Person has 0 or more addresses represented by the Address entity.

In terms of basic API we'd have:

```
POST:    /api/v1/person
GET:     /api/v1/person/{id}
PUT:     /api/v1/person/{id}
DELETE:  /api/v1/person/{id}
```

Then we have 2 ways to retrieve the addresses for a person:

1. `/api/v1/person/{id}/addresses`
2. `/api/v1/addresses/{personId}`

We feel it's more natural to pick the former option `/person/{id}/addresses` for GET but at the same time if we wanna retrieve an address by its id it should be `/api/v1/address/{id}`.

The question is, is there a convention in dealing with POST, PUT and DELETE calls? To me it makes sense that these should be called to the address service at `/api/v1/address OR /api/v1/address/{id}` but at the same time I can see why someone would POST to `/api/v1/person/{id}/address' instead of passing the person id in the request body.

So yeah, can you guys point us in the right direction here - is there a written or unwritten rule in API design when it comes to parent -> child relations?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can an address exist without a person? If the answer is yes, then an address should be a resources of its own.

- `/api/v1/addresses`: the collection of all addresses
- `/api/v1/addresses/{addressId}`: a single address
- `/api/v1/addresses?person={personId}`: all addresses for a person

I'd not use `/api/v1/addresses/{personId}` because it is not immediately obvious that `personId` is the ID of a person, not of an addresse.

But at the same time, `/api/v1/person/{id}/addresses` should be available to navigate from a person to all his addresses.

If an address can not exist without a person, only use `/api/v1/person/{id}/addresses`.

Comment: Totally agree with what you're saying. Wanted to make sure there are no hidden conventions that I wasn't aware of. Thanks for the reply!